# Let $A = 2*p_1*...*p_n + 1$ where $p_i$'s are odd primes . Prove that $\gcd(A,p_i) = 1$ for all $i$.

Tags: number-theory

I'm trying to prove this but I can't figure it out. I'm pretty much stuck. Trying to start with $B = 2*p_1* \dots * p_n$ and clearly the $\gcd(B, p_i) = p_i$ for some $i$.

But adding $1$, I can't figure out how to prove that the $\gcd(A, p_i) = 1$, any hints to lead me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First approach**: Since $$A+p_i\cdot(-2\cdot p_1\cdots p_{i-1}p_{i+1}\cdots p_n)=1$$ then [Bezout's identity](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity) implies that $\gcd(A,p_i)=1.$

**Second approach**: Suppose, for the sake of contradiction, that $d=\gcd(A,p_i)>1$ for some $i.$ If $q$ is any prime factor of $d,$ then $q$ divides both $p_i$ and $A$ and thus $p_i=qb$ and $A=qc$ for some $b,c\in\mathbb Z.$ Hence $( 2p_1\cdots p_{i-1}bp_{i+1}\cdots p_n-c )q=1$ and so $q\mid1,$ which is clearly false since $q$ is prime.

Comment: Not sure how this hint helps, what you're saying is true. But I can't really figure out how this will lead me to the direction proving that the $\gcd$ is $1$

Comment: @John You may want to prove and remember the result that for integers $a, b, x, y$, you have $ax+by=1$, then $\gcd(a, b) = 1$.  This is quite useful.

Comment: @John I added more details.

Comment: does your second approach has some typing error in last line?